# How to access variable in React.js component class

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs

If I have

```
const stateData = [
{
    'id': 'AL',
    'name': 'Alabama',
    'capital': 'Montgomery',
    'date': 'December 14, 1819'
}, 
{
    'id': 'AK',
    'name': 'Alaska',
    'capital': 'Juneau',
    'date': 'January 3, 1959'
}];

const SearchBarAndResults = React.createClass({
  render() {
    // QUESTION: how do I access variable stateData here and replace field
    // from 'id': 'AL' to 'id': 'AK'?
  }
});
```

Comment: Well given this code example, since you are not using modules and the code appears written in the same scope, you can just access `stateData` from any function in your component.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the const **stateData** in to your component like this example, then you have access to the component scope data using {this.props.data} in your component.

```
React.render(<SearchBarAndResults data={stateData[0]} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

This is a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/diegochavez/5q644d53/2/

Best,